# Render formatted numeric value in Zend_Form text field

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a text field in a `Zend_Form` that contains a numeric value. I would like that value to be rendered as though it had been run through `number_format()`. For example, if the value in the field is `12345`, I would like it to appear in the text field as `12,345`.

On the submit side, I have a filter that strips the comma, giving me a clean numeric value when I eventually call `$form->getValues()`. [For the moment, let's forget about the locale issue]

But how do I format the value that ultimately appears in the input field?

I guess I could:

1. create a custom element class extending `Zend_Form_Element_Text`
2. create a custom view helper extending the `FormText` helper
3. set the custom element to use the custom helper
4. add the `ViewHelper`decorator on the form element itself
5. register all required paths/prefixes with all the forms and elements

But it sure seems like a whole lotta hoops through which to jump. Anything simpler?

Comment: I think you bring up a good point. It would be good if there was a decorator that achieved this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Zend_Locale_Format](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.parsing.html) and set the value on your form element

```
$element->setValue(Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber($value, array('number_format' => $xx, 'locale' => $lang_LOCALE));)
```